# Change default order of the sheets in the Book object in pyexcel

Tags: python, pyexcel

I'm trying to created a WorkBook using pyexcel follow this [tutorial](http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/tutorial04.html). But I note when I execute this code

```
import pyexcel

content = {
     'c':
         [
             [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
             [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
             [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
         ],
     'b':
         [
             ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
             [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
             [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
         ],
     'a':
         [
             ['O', 'P', 'Q'],
             [3.0, 2.0, 1.0],
             [4.0, 3.0, 2.0]
         ]
 }

book = pyexcel.Book(content)
print(book)
```

The sheets of the work are in decrease order c, b, a. But the `__str__` version of the `Book` object sort the sheets alphabetically and I want the decrease order like in the dictonary. There is a way of archieve this in pyexcel or other tool? This is es output of the `__str__` version of the `Book`.

```
a:
+-----+-----+-----+
| O   | P   | Q   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
b:
+-----+-----+-----+
| X   | Y   | Z   |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
c:
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4.0 | 5.0 | 6.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 7.0 | 8.0 | 9.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using Pandas for handling excel files.

This tutorial is great to understand its capabilities: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/